# Why was Marvin the referee?

Tags: space-jam, looney-tunes

To give a brief refresh on the plot...

Aliens invade Looney Tune Land and want to enslave Bugs and Co. The plan to save themselves from this fate is a basketball game in which they enlist Michael Jordan to play for them.

The Toon Squad features some of the most notable characters from the show, however one toon in particular is not a member of the team.... **Marvin the Martian**!

Marvin acts as the referee between Monstars and Toon Squad. A referee is supposed to impartial to the game's outcome...

**Did Swackhammer and Bugs agree that Marvin could be impartial because he was both a Toon and an Alien?**

[image: marvin-the-referee]

Comment: I...I forgot that he was in that movie and that was one of my most favorite movies at one point! I am shocked at myself!

Comment: he is a terrible referee since he ignore the obvious performance enhancing that is going on right under his no... er eyes

Comment: @Rincewind one of your most favorite movies? ::rolls newspaper:: bad Rincewind. Bad, bad!

Comment: @Broklynite I was young! I didn't know any better! :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that he is both a Looney Tune and an alien... but he's a martian. He has no affiliation with the other aliens and has no reason to be impartial between the two teams. But considering that the aliens only turned up with 5 members, it's not like they could have provided anyone to act as the referee. Therefore they must have just trusted that he would be the most honest mediator.

I can speculate on two reasons why he may have been chosen to be the referee:

- He is in fact a martian, therefore would have been to space before. Whilst we can assume he would have been taken to space to work at the theme park along with the rest of the Looney Tunes, it's possible that he would have been least opposed to it. Maybe he felt he would have been as happy on any planet as he was on earth, therefore had less objections to going, so less reason than any other Looney Tune to be biased towards their team.
- If I remember correctly from the cartoons, Marvin was particularly fastidious and law-abiding (for a Looney Tune at least). Despite originating from one camp and possibly having an agenda (wanting to go to space or wanting to stay on earth) he was still the best candidate available to act unbiased and allow a fair game.

Comment: Stupid disappearing comments. I would also add that Marvin also has no interest in invading Earth but rather in destroying it. As such his interests do not coincide with either team, allowing him neutrality.